# 'table' undeclared (first use this in a function)

Tags: c, linux, hashtable

So I'm not sure why this isn't working, I'm creating a new table and setting it to the variable 'table' Is there something I'm doing wrong?

This is the error I get when trying to run it:

> src/simpleshell.c:19:3: error: ‘table’ undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> src/simpleshell.c:19:3: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in

My code is as follows:

```
#include "parser.h"
#include "hash_table.h"
#include "variables.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char input[MAXINPUTLINE];
  table = Table_create();
  signal_c_init();
  
  printf("\nhlsh$ ");

  while(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin)){
     stripcrlf(input);
     parse(input);
     printf("\nhlsh$ ");
  }
  Table_free(table);
  return 0;
}
```

Then this is my create a table in the hash_table file:

```
struct Table *Table_create(void){
    struct Table *t;
    t = (struct Table*)calloc(1, sizeof(struct Table));
    return t;
}
```

From the hash_table.c:

```
#include "hash_table.h"
#include "parser.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include "variables.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct Table *table;

unsigned int hash(const char *x){
    int i;
    unsigned int h = 0U;
    for (i=0; x[i]!='\0'; i++){
        h = h * 65599 + (unsigned char)x[i];
    }
    return h % 1024;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should declare `table`'s type. That is,

```
struct Table *table = Table_create();
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed it but in the other file, the hash_table.c I also declared it by "struct Table *table;" why didn't it recognize it through there? Am I doing something wrong that it's not reading that correctly?

Comment: Do you mean you've declared a _global_ `struct Table *table;` in hash_table.c?

Comment: I think I figured it out, I didn't include a line in the hash_table.h,

This specific line:

extern struct Table *table;